# Declaring variables in JavaScript class: this vs. var. Difference?

Tags: javascript, html

What's the difference between declaring internal variables inside a JavaScript class with **this** vs **var**?

Example:

```
function Foo( ) {
   var tool = 'hammer';
}

function Foo2( ) {
   this.tool = 'hammer';
}
```

One difference we're aware of is Foo2.tool will yield "hammer" whereas Foo.tool will yield undefined.

Are there other differences? Recommendations for one vs. the other?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, obviously the serve different purposes. If you don't have any reason to use `this.tool`, use `var tool`.

Comment: Thanks, Blender! Would you mind elaborating on the different purposes they serve?

Comment: Since you can't use `var tool` outside of the class, it isn't made to be used outside of the class. `this.tool` is made to be called from outside of the class.

Comment: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there is no "one or the other" here since the purpose of the two are different.

consider this:

```
var Melee = function(){

    //private property
    var tool = 'hammer';

    //private method
    var attack = function(){
        alert('attack!');
    };

    //public property
    this.weapon = 'sword';

    //public methods
    this.getTool = function(){
        return tool; //can get private property tool
    };
    this.setTool = function(name){
        tool = name; //can set private property tool
    };
};

var handitem = new Melee();
var decoration = new Melee();

//public
handitem.weapon;                 //sword
handitem.getTool();              //hammer
handitem.setTool('screwdriver'); //set tool to screwdriver
handitem.getTool();              //is now screwdriver

//private. will yield undefined
handitem.tool;
handitem.attack();

//decoration is totally different from handitem
decoration.getTool();            //hammer
```

- `handitem.weapon` in OOP is a "public property", accessible from the outside. if i created this instance of `Melee`, i can access and modify `weapon` since it's open to the public.
- `handitem.tool` is a "private property". it's only accessible from inside the object. it is not visible, not accessible, and not modifiable (at least directly) from the outside. trying to access it will return `undefined`
- `handitem.getTool` is a "public method". since it's on the inside of the object, it has access the private property `tool` and get it for you from the outside. sort of bridge to the private world.
- `handitem.attack` is a private method. like all private stuff, it can only be accessed from the inside. in this example, there is no way to call `attack()` (so we are safe from attack :D )

Comment: Thanks, Joseph. To clarify, if we create different instances of Melee, will each one get its own copy of "tool"? Or will updating one overwrite "tool" for the others?

Comment: nope, everytime you call `new Melee()` creates another object. updating a property of one will not change the value of the other.

Comment: When you use the `new` keyword, a new and unique object will be created and passed to the `Melee` function. Thus each will have its own separate `weapon` property. However, in @Joseph`s code, the `tool` variable is a function-scope variable, so you cannot alter it directly from outside the function. You would need a `setTool` method for that.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! One last clarification: if we have a new function called "buyTool", do we need "this.getTool()" or "getTool()" to invoke the "getTool" function inside of the "buyTool" function?

Comment: where is this `buyTool()` located? is it in the object? is it private or public?

Comment: Inside the object. It's another public method of Melee.

Comment: since it's in the object already, it has access to the public as well as private methods. if your aim is to get the `tool` property using `buyTool()`, get it directly instead. your `buyTool()` is already inside.

Comment: No, sorry ... bad example. The aim wasn't to get the tool property, but just to ask how to invoke one public method inside another. Do I need to use "this.getTool()" or just "getTool()"?